# is google::protobuf::RepeatedField<int>::iterator incrementable? compare to const int*/int*

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae, decltype

What's the difference in type deduction? The second line fails, but why?

```
decltype(++std::declval<int*&>()) pri = {nullptr}; 
decltype(++(std::begin(std::declval<google::protobuf::RepeatedField<int>&>()))) nr{nullptr};
```

> error: lvalue required as increment operand

Despite the fact that the following assertion passes:

```
using iterator = decltype((std::begin(std::declval<google::protobuf::RepeatedField<int>&>())));
static_assert(std::is_same_v<iterator, int*>);
```

A `RepeatedField<int>` definitely has a `int*` as an iterator, which is incrementable, so how come the result of `std::begin` cannot be incremented?

Generally, my problem is with the detection of whether a type is a *"range"*.
The code below works and recognizes `RepeatedField` as range.
However, when using SFINAE with functions, it doesn't work. (`is_range_helper<T>(0)` which too could be fixed by `std::next`)

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_range: std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_range<T, std::void_t<decltype(
    ++std::begin(std::declval<T&>()),
    std::begin(std::declval<T&>()), 
    std::end(std::declval<T&>()),    
    ++std::begin(std::declval<T&>()), // problem here
    *std::begin(std::declval<T&>()) 
)>> : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: Why do you spam the language versions? Do you use both C++14 and C++17 in your code?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `std::begin` doesn't return an lvalue reference, but a prvalue.
Let's examine the two types closer:

```cpp
decltype(++std::declval<int*&>()) pri = { nullptr };
```

Here, `std::declval` gives us an `int*&`, which is converted to an lvalue of type `int*` in the expression.
This allows us to use the pre-increment operator, which preserves the value category.

Furthermore, `decltype` results in `int*&`, and this lvalue reference cannot bind to a prvalue of type `nullptr`.
That declaration is ill-formed, but the type is well-formed.

---

```
decltype(++(std::begin(std::declval<google::protobuf::RepeatedField<int>&>()))) nr{nullptr};
```

In this example, `std::begin()` would return a prvalue of type `RepeatedField<int>::iterator`, and the pre-increment operator cannot be applied to it.
The type is ill-formed, and the declaration as a whole is ill-formed.

On a side note, iterators might support pre-increment of prvalues, if the increment is an operator overload, not a builtin operator.
However, [`google::protobuf::RepatedField`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/api-docs/google.protobuf.repeated_field/) has an `iterator` which is defined as:

```cpp
typedef Element* iterator;
```

... so all the regular restrictions apply.

##### Solution

Generally, there are a lot more requirements for iterators than just being incrementable.
We could create the traits to detect all the different requirements for e.g. a [*ForwardIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator), but it would be a lot of effort.

Thankfully, for any iterators satisfying the requirements of iterators, [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) exists and lets us access all information about them, such as the iterator category.
For example, we can detect that something is a [*ForwardIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) by checking the type of the alias `std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category`.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

// convenience alias to get the iterator type of a range
template <typename T>
using iterator_t = decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T&>()));

// primary template for types that don't have any iterator traits
// use void_t idiom for member detection
template <typename Range, typename Traits = void>
struct is_forward_range_impl : std::false_type {};

// substitution will succeed only if we can use std::begin and std::end,
// and if the range's iterator has std::iterator_traits
template <typename Range>
struct is_forward_range_impl<
    Range,
    std::void_t<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<Range&>())),
                decltype(std::end(std::declval<Range&>())),
                std::iterator_traits<iterator_t<Range>>>>
{
private:
    using traits = std::iterator_traits<iterator_t<Range>>;
    using category = typename traits::iterator_category;
    using value_type = typename traits::value_type;

public:
    static inline constexpr bool value
        = std::is_convertible_v<category, std::forward_iterator_tag>;
};
```

All that is left is giving this implementation a proper interface:

```cpp
// proper type trait with no extraneous template parameters
template <typename Range>
struct is_forward_range : is_forward_range_impl<Range> {};

// convenience variable template
template <typename Range>
inline constexpr bool is_forward_range_v = is_forward_range<Range>::value;
```

We can use this trait as follows:

```
// should pass
static_assert(is_forward_range_v<int[10]>);
static_assert(is_forward_range_v<std::array<int, 10>>);

// should pass too
struct S {};
static_assert(!is_forward_range_v<S>);
```

*See [live example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/64TooW58E)*

Comment: But why does decltype(++(std::begin(std::declval<google::protobuf::RepeatedField<int>&>()))) used in void_t suddenly work. is_range detects RepeatedField.

Comment: @KamilPłani I can't reproduce what you're describing. Can you modify this example to make the assertion pass? https://godbolt.org/z/T83GqYfEM